# Android Not Granting Dump Permission

Tags: android, permissions, dump

For the purposes of monitoring Battery usage etc. I have code that executes a few dumpsys calls, reads and parses the output to extract data that I am interested in.

*dumpsys battery*, *dumpsys statusbar*, and *dumpsys power* all give me an error message for output like "Permission Denial: can't dump Battery service from pid..." 
Also, when the application is launched there is an item in the log tagged with "PackageManager" statingNot granting permission android.permissionDUMP to package.... (protectionLevel = 3 ...)"

However, *dumpsys cpuinfo* and *dumpsys netstat* work and give me the correct output, which seems to be inconsistent.

I am able to generate *dumpsys battery* and the like from the adb shell, but when I try to call it programmatically it does not work.

I have tried running this on a HTC Nexus One phone as well as the emulator and get the same results for each.  The weird thing is that this code worked on my Nexus One a day ago (before I upgraded from 2.2 to 2.3), and now it does not.  Is this because of the upgrade?

An example of the code I am trying to run is as follows:

```
        String command = "dumpsys battery";
    try {
        String s = null;
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);


          BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                     InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
                     InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

                // read the output from the command
                System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
                while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }

                // read any errors from the attempted command
                System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
                while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How do I get the *dumpsys* to give me the correct output programmatically and how to I get the *dump permission* to be granted?

*The Nexus One is not rooted and I would like to get this working without having to root it for the purposes of my project

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 8):

Regular applications cannot get the DUMP permission. It is reserved to system applications.

Answer (score 1):

android.permission.Dump is protected by system, signature, and development permission protection levels. Line 1993 of [the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-mr1-release/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml) shows you this. If your APK is signed with the framework cert, is in the priv-app directory, or debuggable (see below) you can use the pm service to grant the permission, but otherwise the code specifically prevents what you're asking for (line 2624 of [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-mr1-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java)).

Debuggable APKs can be created through setting the debuggable attribute on a buildType via build.gradle. Sample Android DSL:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            ...
        }
        quality_assurance {
            debuggable true
        }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your handset had been rooted, 'dumpsys activity' will work on Android2.3:

```
private static void dumpIT0(String sCmd) {
    try {
        String s = null;
        String command = "su -c " + sCmd;
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                process.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                process.getErrorStream()));

        // read the output from the command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        // read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e);
    }
}
sCmd = "dumpsys activity";
```